# Increment Number within a Concatenated String based on conditional if

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, backup, microsoft-excel-2007

I am trying to Increment a Number based on a conditional `IF` in another column.

[image: example]

In Column A I have a `=Concatenate("ABC","_",D2)`.

I am looking to fill down a formula that will basically be an `=if(C6=C5,B5,Concatenate("ABC","_",D2+1)`.

However, I would like to fill down across hundreds of rows. Is this possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking for the keyboard shortcut to fill down or fill across? Or did you need help with the formula? The sample data labels column A & B but the formula references B, C & D. Please provide accurate and complete details.

Comment: First, if `D2` has the "starting number", you need to make that an absolute reference in your formula (`$D$2`). Second, what about for Column B: `="Text "&MID(A5,SEARCH("_",A5)+1,LEN(A5)-SEARCH("_",A5))`, where `A5` is the start of your `ABC_1`?

Comment: I want to manipulate the number behind ABC (the 1,2,3 in column A) based on the Text in column b (That is constant). The picture is the end result I am looking for. But I would like a formula that could increment a number that starts from a reference, but is part of a concatenate function.
The formula I have is what I am thinking it should look like, but it wont work because it will always just go from 1 to 2 over and over again, never increasing past 2. There is probably a better way then to have a "starting value" but I couldn't think of one.

Answer (score 0):

Your sequence hinges on a unique count of the values in column C.

```
=CONCATENATE("ABC","_",D$2-1+SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(C$6:C6,C$6:C6)))
```

[image]

If column C is not sorted, perform a lookup and use the unique number when there is no match.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B$5:B5, MATCH(C6, C$5:C5, 0)), CONCATENATE("ABC","_", D$2-1+SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(C$6:C6,C$6:C6))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest hassle free and simple method to create Series in desire order.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- I'm assuming the data is in Range `A3:A11`.
- Enter **ABC** in `A1`.
- Write Formula in `C3` and fill down.

  `=$A$1&"-"&RIGHT(A3,1)`

**In case you may have pattern where Digits are more than 1 as suffix with TEXT, then you need to use Formula shown below.**

[image]

```
=$A$1&"-"&RIGHT(A3,LEN(A3) - MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, A3&"0123456789")) +1)
```

**N.B.**

- Since Pattern is fixed like, **1 for 1, 2 
  for 2 and so further as suffix with 
  ABC**, therefore this method will works 
  smoothly.
- You may adjust cell reference in formula 
  as needed.